# Rotating the stroke but not the filling of a svg circle

Tags: css, animation, svg, css-transforms

I've followed [this tuto](https://css-tricks.com/building-progress-ring-quickly/#article-header-id-7) in order to implement a progress ring for my Vue application. I still have an extra requirement: fill the circle with an image. That's the point I've reached to, using a pattern (copy pasted from my browser in order to avoid adding the extra complexity of Vue property evaluations):

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <svg
    height="600"
    width="600">
    <defs>
      <pattern id="service" x="0%" y="0%" height="100%" width="100%"
              viewBox="0 0 100 100">
        <image x="5" y="5" width="90" height="90" href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/7a/Selfie_icon.svg/2000px-Selfie_icon.svg.png"></image>
      </pattern>
      <linearGradient id="gradient">
        <stop offset="0%"  stop-color="#f6921e"/>
        <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#f6921e88"/>
      </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <circle
        stroke="url(#gradient)"
        stroke-dasharray="1709.0264035528476 1709.0264035528476"
        style="stroke-dashoffset: 512.708;"
        stroke-linecap="round"
        stroke-width="14"
        fill="url(#service)"
        r="272"
        cx="300"
        cy="300"
    />
    </svg>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
circle {
  transition: stroke-dashoffset 0.35s;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
```

However, I find that rotating the circle obviously rotates its filling too.

[image]

Is there any way to overcome this problem? Why does the example rotate the entire SVG to make the circle gap be in the upside?

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mjVQOB)

Comment: Draw two circles, one rotated with the stroke, and one not with the fill. Alternatively don't rotate at all but change the stroke-dashoffset values instead. Option 3 rotate the image in the pattern the other way.

Answer (score 2):

You can use another circle in your SVG, one for the border and one for the background, then rotate just the circle with the border:

```css
.circle-border {
  transition: stroke-dashoffset 0.35s;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
<div>
  <svg height="600" width="600">
    <defs>
      <pattern id="service" x="0%" y="0%" height="100%" width="100%" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
        <image x="5" y="5" width="90" height="90" href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/7a/Selfie_icon.svg/2000px-Selfie_icon.svg.png"></image>
      </pattern>
      <linearGradient id="gradient">
        <stop offset="0%"  stop-color="#f6921e"/>
        <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#f6921e88"/>
      </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <circle
      stroke="url(#gradient)"
      stroke-dasharray="1709.0264035528476 1709.0264035528476"
      style="stroke-dashoffset: 512.708;"
      stroke-linecap="round"
      stroke-width="14"
      fill="transparent"
      class="circle-border"
      r="272"
      cx="300"
      cy="300"
    />
    <circle
      stroke-width="0"
      fill="url(#service)"
      class="circle-bg"
      r="272"
      cx="300"
      cy="300"
    />
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out! I've finally gone with Robert Longson's option 3: rotate the pattern the other way. Even if I don't consider it the most elegant way :-(